# Can't use cocoa pod modules once installed into Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have install this [cocoapod](https://github.com/tatsu/OpenSphericalCamera) successfully and I am now running the workspace project instead of the Xcode project so I can successfully see the pod in the navigator.

I am now trying to import the module into my class by typing:

> import OpenSphericalCamera

but I just get this error

> No such module 'OpenSphericalCamera'

Are there further steps I need to do before being able to import modules into my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please dont name your Project copied of the framework you installed. Or try `Cmd` + `Shift` + `K` (Clean build), or just Build it first (`Cmd` + `B`)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both of these as well as closing and reopening Xcode and its still not showing up

Comment: Are you sure about Your Project name, make sure Your Project Name is different from you FrameWork. Its the mainly reason of No Such File Module. And make sure you open `.xcworkspace` NOT `.xcodeproj`

Comment: Yes I am sure. My project is called **TBA HDR** and I am opening the **.xcworkspace**. Do I need to import the frameworks as well as install the cocoapod?

Comment: Did you run `pod install` in Terminal? Please check version of the Framework you want to install, please name it like `pod 'OpenSphericalCamera', '~> 3.0.0'`. If it still does work, pls run `pod repo update OpenSphericalCamera`. After that, Quit Xcode and open your project -> clean build your project again -> build -> and run.

Comment: My podfile is correct. However, when I try and run **pod repo update OpenSphericalCamera** in terminal the error I get is **[!] The `OpenSphericalCamera` repo is not a git repo.**

Comment: I have it working now. I checked my cocoapod and I had a typo on my target. I corrected that, reinstalled and ran Xcode and all works now. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulation!

Answer (score 0):

Try close xcode and reopen. Maybe the error gone ^_^

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but it still isn't working.